# How to concatenate vectors defined as functions from finite types

Tags: coq

I've defined vector types on a type `A` by using functions as `fin n -> A`. I cannot come up with a way for concatenating the vectors without going through inductive vectors.

The definition of finite sets I am using is

```
Fixpoint fin (k : nat) : Type :=
  match k with
  | 0 => False
  | S k => option (fin k)
  end.
```

Then I define vectors of size `k` as functions `fin k -> A`.

How can I concatenate such vectors?

```
concat {A : Type} (n m : nat) (v1 : fin n -> A) (v2 : fin m -> A) (i : fin (n + m)) : A
```

I've tried pattern matching on `n`, but it doesn't seem to acknowledge then that `i` is of type `fin m` then in the `0` case.

I guess this is a well-known definition, but I couldn't find this variant of vectors. Maybe moving from this type to vectors in Coq's library, concatenate there, and then come back, is an option, but I would like to have a more direct approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to write a case analysis operator to decide whether the input to the concatenated function is on the `n` side or the `m` side:

```
Fixpoint fin n :=
  match n with
  | 0 => Empty_set
  | S n => option (fin n)
  end.

Fixpoint case_fin n m : fin (n + m) -> fin n + fin m :=
  match n return fin (n + m) -> fin n + fin m with
  | 0 => fun i => inr i
  | S n => fun i =>
             match i with
             | None => inl None
             | Some j => match case_fin n m j with
                         | inl j => inl (Some j)
                         | inr j => inr j
                         end
             end
  end.

Fixpoint concat {A} n m (f : fin n -> A) (g : fin m -> A) (i : fin (n + m)) : A :=
  match case_fin n m i with
  | inl i => f i
  | inr i => g i
  end.
```